HTTP as a protocol and an URI has standard metadata names. Is there any equivalence for other protocols or URIs?
For webpages, like https://example.com, you have standard metadata names like author, description. Is there any equivalence for other URI, like mailto:test@example.com? I know that for an email you can extract the message header field names, but here I ask for email address only.
I have a feeling that the answer is no, because for whatever the protocol is used, the server must respond something to the request. For the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP), a HTML page containing <meta> tags are typically responded. But for SMTP, I'm not so sure. I have a feeling that SMTP wasn't created with an intention to send response for any request. Is that correct?
Skimming Uniform Resource Identifier - Wikipedia or Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) - Wikipedia I don't see where this is mentioned.

mailto supports subject, cc, bcc, and even body text in the URI. Ex: mailto:ex@example.com?subject=This%20is%20an%20email

As another example, FTP supports username, password, port, and path as optional standard parameters in the URI.

I'm aware of that, but I'm looking for standards of the response. Or perhaps I should understand how are the request and response be different in different protocols. And do different URIs use different protocols?

To the best of my knowledge, a URI is just what you use to get to a particular resource, so the expected response is defined by the protocol; it's not really a URI thing. The way I would put it, different protocols define (and lay claim to) different URIs.

to make an analogy, would you say URI be like your home address: it's just a name for people to differentiate them, while protocol is how the post office works?

That analogy sounds right to me, yes. A URI is like an address or a phone number, it's just an identifier (and indeed telephone numbers are supported under the URI spec - that's why you can make telephone numbers into web hyperlinks that open a dialer on a smartphone). A protocol is more like the details of how mail is routed and delivered, or how a phone call actually reaches your handset and gets translated from a data stream into sound.

So I take that it's totally possible to return a text response via HTTP when the user visits mailto:example@email.com on the browser, instead of having it switch to an email client? But then what server will response to it? How does the browser finds out that server?

No, there's no way to return a text response for that. No web server or HTTP is involved after you click the mailto link (assuming you've got a native email client and not a web email client). The browser knows it can't speak the protocol referred to by the URI, so it switches to a different piece of software that it knows can speak that protocol.

So each URI requires a counterpart protocol (and thus a counterpart client) to transfer data? Is it theoretically impossible to cross-using URI and protocol, or is it that it's just not optimized to do so? Since from the analogy, I think you can theoretically use do so, though of course that's not optimized/practical.

When you click on an identifier (URI), your device typically passes the identifier to a piece of software that understands it. Then, the software typically uses the identifier to take an action on your behalf (open up an email compose window, or establish a connection to an FTP server, or prompt you to call a phone number.) Indeed to the best of my understanding each URI has a counterpart protocol, so it requires a software client that speaks that corresponding protocol in order to handle the URI. It's not exactly clear to me what you mean when you say "cross-using" URI and protocol.

I mean using SMTP to visit http:, or HTTP to visit fpt:. Is that clearer?

I think I got it. Yeah, you can't mix and match. That would sort of be like trying to call a street address or deliver mail to a phone number. The way you're expected to use the identifier (URI) is implied by the identifier's type. Theoretically you could have a web browser that could handle SMTP + mailto links itself without any additional software, but by definition that would make it an email client. And if you had a web browser that supported ftp links, that would by definition make it also an ftp client (in fact many web browsers used to include ftp capabilities back in the 2000s).
